# How to reset a form element to its ordinary default value?

Tags: forms, entities

I do a form alter on a node form and make some callbacks which restrict value lists in a < select > element, which is a entity reference. When the triggering element is changed, I want to load the node forms default value just like it is in the beginning of the form process.
I remember there was an api function to do that. Someone nows it?

Comment: Just a note, but you might want to write a ctools entity reference selection tool plugin instead. e.g: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/53177/7153

Answer (score 6):

[field_get_default_value](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_default_value/7) - Helper function to get the default value for a field on an entity.
Usage:

```
<?php
  $field = field_info_field('YOURFIELDNAME');
  $instance = field_info_instance('node', 'YOURFIELDNAME', 'YOURNODETYPE');
  $defvalue = field_get_default_value('node', $node, $field, $instance, $node->language);
  print_r($defvalue); // Here structure, like $defvalue[0]['value']
?>
```