# Can I make interaction between views relations and views arguments?

Tags: views, nodes

I'm running into the problem where I have to join a node and a registration. The nodes are of type 'event' and the registration is available for some, but not all of them.

So basically I have a list of event nodes, and I left join the registrations on them, giving me some extra information where available.

The problem is I want to list only my registrations. So a contextual filter has to be added somewhere. The problem; The default filter applies after the join, filtering also all nodes for which I have not yet registered. But I want to show those.

Therefor I am looking for a custom handler that allows me to add an 'extra' statement to the views join clause. I've looked for it, but started t doubt where such  a thing is actually possible. Had anyone ever tried such a thing?

I suppose I need to make a custom hander, it's not a problem. But can handers 'communicate', or is there something like a hybrid handler of some sort?

**Wrong query**

```
SELECT ...
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {node_registration} node_registration_node ON node.nid = node_registration_node.nid
WHERE (( (node_registration_node.uid = '1' )
```

**Working query, but non contextual**

```
SELECT ...
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {node_registration} node_registration_node ON node.nid = node_registration_node.nid AND node_registration_node.uid = '1'
```

Comment: I would say your question is more of an sql question than a drupal one. There are various modules available for event registration. Have you looked at https://drupal.org/project/registration

Comment: Yes Andrew, I used that module first. But that was lacking the same functionality. I'm probably looking for a custom argument-handler that can alter or override the relationship-handler. If only I knew if such a thing was possible...

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82165/override-entityreference-autocomplete-and-return-entityfieldquery-output this might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions Andrew, I ended up creating a custom argument-handler. It adds one (or more) extra conditions to the join. `LEFT JOIN ... AND ...`.

```
function query($group_by = FALSE) {
  $this->ensure_my_table();

    $this->query->table_queue[$this->table_alias]['join']->extra = array(
      array('table' => $this->table_alias, 'field' => $this->real_field, 'value' => $this->argument),
    );
  }
}
```