# Show node IDs along with titles in Entity reference Autocomplete list

Tags: 7, views, nodes, entities, ajax

I'll like to add this functionality to the autocomplete widget in Entityreference field to show node ID next to the titles in the dropdown list. The reason behind the idea is to differentiate between multiple nodes with same title.

Example:

- This is a title (3)
- This is a title (2)
- This is a title (1)

I know the node ID is shown once a selection is made but I like to show it in the dropdown list in order to pick the right node quickly based on the node ID.

Comment: take a look at this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82165/override-entityreference-autocomplete-and-return-entityfieldquery-output/82665#82665

Comment: @oksana-c check my answer with another easy way

Answer (score 22):

Install the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) modules, create a new View and Add a Entity Reference Display:

[image]

Then Add in the fields the content title and the nid, click in the nid and check Exclude from display, Save and click in the title and go to rewrite the output of the title as `[title] - ([nid])`

[image]
[image]

Go to edit the settings of the format and check the title, this will allow you to search by title.

[image]

Save the view.

Go to edit your Entity Reference field and select in the Mode Views: .... (like the following image) and select your View (in this case the name is: articles_with_id) and save the settings:

[image]

Then go to see the result:

[image]

**EDIT:** This is now working in Drupal 8, at least in the version 8.3.4.

Comment: OMG, I always wondered what the views option was for. This is filthy!!!

Comment: @NoSssweat I'm learning english now, can you provide me a synonym of filthy please? I can't understand the phrase "This is filthy"

Comment: Synonym: **Dirty**. I used it as an expression, should be taken **[figuratively and not literally](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wa7TvxC2rgA).**

Comment: @NoSssweat Then is a bad solution?

Comment: No, it means it's a really good/impressive solution. Ex: [Alexander Nylander's Filthy Shootout Goal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fRUV53sOh8)

Comment: @NoSssweat thanks, I learning English too in this site ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I agree this solution is "sick"! [(idiom)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idiom)

Comment: @JohnR is sick in a good way or in a bad way? Remember that I learning english now, and sick is unwell, this confuse me a little ;-)

Comment: The only problem with this solution, is that the entity reference field, once selected, shows the ID twice in the entity edit form, because it is included by default once it is selected.

Comment: @Yuri Yes, I will see if I find a solution for this. thanks

Comment: Does anyone know if this works for the user entity as well. No matter how I seem to set it up it always displays the email address (user) and not firstname / lastname from the associated user entity. Great walk through btw!

Comment: @ShawnMatthews I think that will work, but I never made the test, you can follow the steps and test with users, if this works share here your results ;-)

Comment: Incase anyone stumbles across this. Its currently broken in 8.0+ https://www.drupal.org/node/2174633

Comment: @ShawnMatthews this is now working in drupal 8.3.4

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Im using Drupal 8.6+patch in above url (if I click 'Add Existing Badge', the entity view/autocomplete works). But I'm curious y this dropdown shows in the field's display: https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7856/46769243104_db4bcfa2e6_z.jpg

If I change the field to use the 'Default' Reference Method and pick my 'Badge' type, then there is no dropdown. Settings for that: 
https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7816/47492694801_abd94f7970_z.jpg
vs settings for Entity Ref field which causes the dropdown to show up: https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7909/46577339485_e124628460_z.jpg

Comment: Adding to my above comment... in the 'Manage form display' settings of the Badge content type, the "Allow users to add new badges#2" is what adds that dropdown. its smart to recognize to only use Badge content type in the 'Add Existing' autocomplete since my entity ref view specifically filters on Badges, but the 'Add new' button doesn't use this view reference im guessing (since its not an autocomplete), so have to manually pick which content type you want to add. I wonder if there is a fix for this (like a way in the field settings to say 'use Badges in with Add New functionality')

Comment: @armyofda12mnkeys I really don't know, I'm not working with this feature now.

Answer (score 5):

Create Entity Reference field with the default configuration

[image]

The function [entityreference_autocomplete_callback_get_matches](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entityreference!entityreference.module/function/entityreference_autocomplete_callback_get_matches/7) determines what the output of the autocomplete should be.

```
function entityreference_autocomplete_callback_get_matches($type, $field, $instance, $entity_type, $entity_id = '', $string = '') {
  $matches = array();

  $entity = NULL;
  if ($entity_id !== 'NULL') {
    $entity = entity_load_single($entity_type, $entity_id);
    $has_view_access = (entity_access('view', $entity_type, $entity) !== FALSE);
    $has_update_access = (entity_access('update', $entity_type, $entity) !== FALSE);
    if (!$entity || !($has_view_access || $has_update_access)) {
      return MENU_ACCESS_DENIED;
    }
  }

  $handler = entityreference_get_selection_handler($field, $instance, $entity_type, $entity);

  if ($type == 'tags') {
    // The user enters a comma-separated list of tags. We only autocomplete the last tag.
    $tags_typed = drupal_explode_tags($string);
    $tag_last = drupal_strtolower(array_pop($tags_typed));
    if (!empty($tag_last)) {
      $prefix = count($tags_typed) ? implode(', ', $tags_typed) . ', ' : '';
    }
  }
  else {
    // The user enters a single tag.
    $prefix = '';
    $tag_last = $string;
  }

  if (isset($tag_last)) {
    // Get an array of matching entities.
    $entity_labels = $handler->getReferencableEntities($tag_last, $instance['widget']['settings']['match_operator'], 10);

    // Loop through the products and convert them into autocomplete output.
    foreach ($entity_labels as $values) {
      foreach ($values as $entity_id => $label) {
        $key = "$label ($entity_id)";
        // Strip things like starting/trailing white spaces, line breaks and tags.
        $key = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", '', trim(decode_entities(strip_tags($key)))));
        // Names containing commas or quotes must be wrapped in quotes.
        if (strpos($key, ',') !== FALSE || strpos($key, '"') !== FALSE) {
          $key = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $key) . '"';
        }
        /* *** */$matches[$prefix . $key] = '<div class="reference-autocomplete">' . $label .' - ('. $entity_id . ')</div>';//****
      }
    }
  }
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

the last line `$matches[$prefix . $key] = '<div class="reference-autocomplete">'` determines the output and the `$entity_id` is available which is the ID. You can do what I did in that line (shown by `**`), simply write:

```
 $matches[$prefix . $key] = '<div class="reference-autocomplete">' . $label .' - ('. $entity_id . ')</div>';
```

you can use `$entity_id` to fetch other fields and anything you want.

## One More Thing!

Some times it is not a good idea to change the function of the core module (if it is not important to you the above solution is enough).

If you need to override the core function of the `entity_reference` module, build a small module and name it `elabel`

it is `elabel.info`

```
;$Id;
name = My Entity Reference Label
description = This module creates special Entity Reference Label
package = My Modules
core = 7.x
php = 5.1
files[] = elabel.module
```

and it is `elabel.module`

```
<?php function elabel_menu_alter(&$items){
    unset($items['entityreference/autocomplete/single/%/%/%']);
    unset($items['entityreference/autocomplete/tags/%/%/%']);

      $items['entityreference/autocomplete/single/%/%/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Entity Reference Autocomplete',
    'page callback' => 'elabel_autocomplete_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(2, 3, 4, 5),
    'access callback' => 'entityreference_autocomplete_access_callback',
    'access arguments' => array(2, 3, 4, 5),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

    $items['entityreference/autocomplete/tags/%/%/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Entity Reference Autocomplete',
    'page callback' => 'elabel_autocomplete_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(2, 3, 4, 5),
    'access callback' => 'entityreference_autocomplete_access_callback',
    'access arguments' => array(2, 3, 4, 5),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;

}

function elabel_autocomplete_callback($type, $field_name, $entity_type, $bundle_name, $entity_id = '', $string = '') {
  // If the request has a '/' in the search text, then the menu system will have
  // split it into multiple arguments and $string will only be a partial. We want
  //  to make sure we recover the intended $string.
  $args = func_get_args();
  // Shift off the $type, $field_name, $entity_type, $bundle_name, and $entity_id args.
  array_shift($args);
  array_shift($args);
  array_shift($args);
  array_shift($args);
  array_shift($args);
  $string = implode('/', $args);

  $field = field_info_field($field_name);
  $instance = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name);

  return elabel_autocomplete_callback_get_matches($type, $field, $instance, $entity_type, $entity_id, $string);
}

function elabel_autocomplete_callback_get_matches($type, $field, $instance, $entity_type, $entity_id = '', $string = '') {
  $matches = array();

  $entity = NULL;
  if ($entity_id !== 'NULL') {
    $entity = entity_load_single($entity_type, $entity_id);
    $has_view_access = (entity_access('view', $entity_type, $entity) !== FALSE);
    $has_update_access = (entity_access('update', $entity_type, $entity) !== FALSE);
    if (!$entity || !($has_view_access || $has_update_access)) {
      return MENU_ACCESS_DENIED;
    }
  }

  $handler = entityreference_get_selection_handler($field, $instance, $entity_type, $entity);

  if ($type == 'tags') {
    // The user enters a comma-separated list of tags. We only autocomplete the last tag.
    $tags_typed = drupal_explode_tags($string);
    $tag_last = drupal_strtolower(array_pop($tags_typed));
    if (!empty($tag_last)) {
      $prefix = count($tags_typed) ? implode(', ', $tags_typed) . ', ' : '';
    }
  }
  else {
    // The user enters a single tag.
    $prefix = '';
    $tag_last = $string;
  }

  if (isset($tag_last)) {
    // Get an array of matching entities.
    $entity_labels = $handler->getReferencableEntities($tag_last, $instance['widget']['settings']['match_operator'], 10);

    // Loop through the products and convert them into autocomplete output.
    foreach ($entity_labels as $values) {
      foreach ($values as $entity_id => $label) {
        $key = "$label ($entity_id)";
        // Strip things like starting/trailing white spaces, line breaks and tags.
        $key = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", '', trim(decode_entities(strip_tags($key)))));
        // Names containing commas or quotes must be wrapped in quotes.
        if (strpos($key, ',') !== FALSE || strpos($key, '"') !== FALSE) {
          $key = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $key) . '"';
        }
        /* *** */ $matches[$prefix . $key] = '<div class="reference-autocomplete">' . $label .'('.$entity_id.')' .'</div>';
      }
    }
  }

  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

**I tried this code and it works perfectly 
If there are other type of entity references and you don't need to do this for them, simply add an `IF` statement and check for bundle or content type.**

Answer (score 1):

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.my_module = {
    attach: function (context) {

      function autocomplete_tid_remove(field) {

        var autocomplete_tid = $(field).val();
        var autocomplete_tid_stripped = autocomplete_tid.replace(/(\([^*]+\))(?=.*\1)/,'');
        $(field).val(autocomplete_tid_stripped);

      }

      jQuery('.form-autocomplete').on('click', function () {
        window.currentElement = jQuery(this);
      });

      jQuery('.form-autocomplete', context).once('my_module').on('autocompleteclose', function () {
        autocomplete_tid_remove(currentElement);
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

@Adrian Cid Almaguer answer is great! But shows nid twice as mentioned by @yuri. I was able to overcome this using js.