# How do I see the ID of a content type record?

Tags: entities

Using Entity Reference, I'm able to create a Field in a Content Type (Person) which references another Content Type (Story). When I go to input link data, I see a list of Title(s) of Story(ies).

How do I know that I have the right story? There are many crime fiction stories with the same title.

Is there a way to expose the Content Type record ID?

Answer (score 0):

When creating your entity reference field there is a "Mode" selection. The default is simple but you can choose to use a Views entity reference display type instead.

So in views if you create a new view (that displays the data you want) and add a entity reference display type to i. You can then use that in your entity reference field.

EDIT: Just seen the comment above referencing [Show node IDs along with titles in Entity reference Autocomplete list](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187869/show-node-ids-along-with-titles-in-entityreference-autocomplete-list) Do that