# How to change the autocomplete for a user reference to show First/Last name instead of username?

Tags: nodes, 8, views, ajax

I want to add a user reference field to an "event" content type, and reference the user who will present.

But I wonder how to change the entity reference - I've tried using the "filter by an entity reference view" with a view I created, but it still only shows the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [Show node IDs along with titles in Entityreference Autocomplete list](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187869/show-node-ids-along-with-titles-in-entityreference-autocomplete-list/187896#187896) except in the rewrite of your user name field use `{{field_first_name}} {{field_last_name}}` and you need to add those fields ABOVE your user name field, in order to get access to those replacement patterns.

Comment: I followed the example step by step, and my autocomplete list is still only showing the normal usernames [e.g., pparker, jjj666, maryjwhat, etc.] and not the full names.

In D8, in my entity reference view username is rewritten as "{{ field_first_name }} {{ field_last_name }}", and the format settings are definitely set for the search fields to be that field. So I'm not sure what's wrong...

Also, I have cleared the cache several times.

Comment: @W0LF ok, I will try this out in D8.

Comment: Yup, everything looks correct...boggling my mind a bit at present. Also, possibly due to the rewrite/view entity reference autocomplete not working - there doesn't seem to be a way to display the rewritten name instead of the username. There also isn't any option in manage display to change what it shows either so "Presenter: maryjwhat" still shows instead of "Presenter: Mary J Watson".

Comment: humm... looks to me that this is a D8 bug. I will try this in D7 to double check

Comment: After doing a search, this has been reported already [Entity Reference inline fields not working as expected](https://www.drupal.org/node/2714089)

Comment: Well shucks - I'll just follow that report until a temp patch or update to fix it in views is committed. Thanks for checking into it as well!