# I want to override results of an autocomplete field (Entity reference in a content)

Tags: views, 8, ajax

I have a content type Intertainment and i made a reference of a view(entity referene).

I used inline entity form complex widget in manage form display the entity reference and i checked "Allow users to add existing jeux".

[image]

When i add/edit the entity reference field of type Intertainment ,  when i click "ajouter une jeu existant - or add jeu existant."

[image]

=> Results of autocomplete are when i taped something its give all titles of references entities like this : 
test taxo 1

My need is to override the array results of autocomplete of inline entity form module and i don't want to add a new widget.

Example add type of content in the key of result array of autocomplete.
[image]

=> What i want to make :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much the same as [Show node IDs along with titles in Entity reference Autocomplete list](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187869/show-node-ids-along-with-titles-in-entity-reference-autocomplete-list/187896#187896) except you use content type name instead of node id.

Currently there is a bug in Drupal 8 where this does not work properly. Here is the issue: [Views Filter by an entity reference view not working as expected](https://www.drupal.org/node/2714089) you could try the patch in [comment #26](https://www.drupal.org/node/2714089#comment-11538853) or the module in [comment #13](https://www.drupal.org/node/2714089#comment-11522833). I have not tried them yet.